# How does Docker Daemon handle large log output?

Tags: logging, docker, elk

I have a number of server applications running in Docker. The output is configured to go to an elk stack.

I've had a number of troubles with the elk stack and am considering going back to vanilla Docker logging. My concern is scalability.

My question is: **How does Docker Daemon handle large log output?**

Comment: Exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: I'm wondering what happens when I drop a Gb of logs in there. Does it truncate or fall over?

Comment: Why do you want to use Elk? What did you try?